# Read from the file from different functions

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to read from the same file from another function but it doesn't work.
I guess the problem is that I'm trying to read from `ifstream &input` but I don't know the other way to implement that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Student{
    public:
    char name[40]; // i cant use string
    int age;

    void Input(ifstream &input)
    {
        input.getline(name, 40);
        input >> age;
    }
};

void Read(Student *students, int &numberOfStudents)
{
    ifstream input("test.txt");

    input >> numberOfStudents;

    students = new Student[numberOfStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; ++i)
        students[i].Input(input);

    input.close();
}

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    Student *students = NULL;

    Read(students, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << students[i].name << endl << students[i].age << endl;

    return 0;  
}
```

I made my input file

```
3
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

(if the program was working correctly i should've get 1 - name age - 2 etc)
but what i got is no names with ages = 1 2 3 respectively

Comment: You don't return the pointer to your students, hence the allocation is only locally, return the pointer and override `students` in main from the return value. Also: You are leaking memory. Can you use vector.

Comment: @n314159 I forgot to write delete. Thanks. I can't use vector (I would like to but i can't). I ran a little test where i did the same thing (not returning the pointer) and my array still had changed values. I'm still gonna try that. Thanks

Comment: Use vector to store student objects. better yet: define constuctor for Student that reads from istream.

Comment: @JATothrim i can't use vector

Comment: Why can't you use `std::string` or `std::vector`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's the task I got

Comment: Oh, it's a teacher imposing those restrictions? Got it ...

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::unique_ptr`? Your program is leaking right now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can use whatever I want as long as i can explain how it works. But here i'm trying to help my friend who doesn't know how the vector works so that's why i can't use it :)

Comment: I'd take the time to explain how both `std::string` and `std::vector` works, roughly. Should save you both a lot of problems in the end.

Comment: I will explain.

Comment: Don't forget to call `delete [] students;` before program termination.

Answer (score 0):

The program does not work because you define:

```
void Read(Student *students, int &numberOfStudents)
```

And then

```
int size = 0;
Student *students = NULL;
Read(students, size);
```

The `students` pointer is passed-by **value** so `Read()` can not change the memory address outside the function.

To fix this simply pass the the pointer by-reference:

```
void Read(Student *& students, int &numberOfStudents)
```

Lastly as I commented you need to account white space e.g. `'\n'` line ending
In the file when using `>>` operator to extract data:

```
void Input(ifstream &input)
{
    input.getline(name, 40);
    input >> age;
    input.ignore(1);
}
```

Same for reading the number of students in the file.

Comment: My function now returns the pointer. Now this part works as it should. But all i get is 3 student objects with no names and ages = 0. The main problems is still in ```void Input()```. Thanks for you suggestion

Comment: Could you link the test.txt file that you are trying to read?

Comment: Reading name with `input >> name;` works. Problem seems that you are not accounting white space correctly in the file, i.e. newline character. Following data works: https://pastebin.com/qt3W7Eh9